# How do i delete the messages on the top

Tags: javascript, chat

I have a working chat system, but when people spam the chat, the chat get longer and the page gets longer and very laggy. How do i remove the messages on the top?

My JavaScript so far:

```js
let username = "Community Bot";
let chatMsg = ["Hello! Welcome to this game. Please press 'i' for instructions!"];

function appendChatMessage(currentUserName, chatMessage) {
  let chatElem = document.createElement("p");
  chatElem.innerHTML = "<strong>" + currentUserName + ": </strong>" + chatMessage;
  document.querySelector(".chat").appendChild(chatElem);
}

for (let i = 0; i < chatMsg.length; i++) {
  appendChatMessage(username, chatMsg[i])
}

let Game = {
  currentGame: {
    variables: {
      Clicks: 0,
      Increment: 1,
      sendMessage: function(messageContent) {
        chatMsg.push(messageContent);
        appendChatMessage(username, messageContent);
        document.querySelector(".enterT").innerHTML = ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My HTML so far:

```html
<div class="chat">
  <h1>CHAT</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="enterT" type="text" placeholder="Enter A Message..!" /><button
    onclick="Game.currentGame.variables.sendMessage(document.querySelector('.enterT').value)"
  >
    send message
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the below implementation

I moved `<h1>CHAT</h1>` out of `<div class="chat"></div>` for only keeping chat message in `<div class="chat"></div>`

```js
let username = "Community Bot";
let chatMsg = ["Hello! Welcome to this game. Please press 'i' for instructions!"];

function appendChatMessage(currentUserName, chatMessage) {
  let chatElem = document.createElement("p");
  chatElem.innerHTML = "<strong>" + currentUserName + ": </strong>" + chatMessage;
  document.querySelector(".chat").appendChild(chatElem);
  document.querySelector(".enterT").value = ""
}

for (let i = 0; i < chatMsg.length; i++) {
  appendChatMessage(username, chatMsg[i])
}

let Game = {
  currentGame: {
    variables: {
      Clicks: 0,
      Increment: 1,
      sendMessage: function(messageContent) {
        if (!messageContent) {
          return
        }
        chatMsg.push(messageContent);
        appendChatMessage(username, messageContent);
      },
      deleteTopMessage: function() {
        const chatElement = document.querySelector(".chat")
        if (chatElement.children[0]) {
          chatElement.removeChild(chatElement.children[0])
        }
        if (chatMsg.length > 0) {
          chatMsg.shift()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  CHAT
</h1>
<div class="chat">
</div>
<div>
  <input class="enterT" type="text" placeholder="Enter A Message..!">
  <button onclick="Game.currentGame.variables.sendMessage(document.querySelector('.enterT').value)">send
    message</button>
  <button onclick="Game.currentGame.variables.deleteTopMessage()">delete top message</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have all your messages in an array and remove them with .pop or .shift?

Comment: Avoid asking questions by posting it as an answer. Use comments instead